# Code for how to stop just on 3 image

Tags: javascript, spinner

Hello guys I follow this tutorial [Roulette Demo](http://demo.st-marron.info/roulette/sample/demo.html), but I want to determine how to stop just on 3 image.

I tried with this code:

```
var defaultSettings = {
            maxPlayCount : null, // x >= 0 or null
            speed : 10, // x > 0
            stopImageNumber : 2,  // x >= 0 or null ors -1
            rollCount : 3, // x >= 0
            duration : 3, //(x second)
            stopCallback : function() {
            },
            startCallback : function() {
            },
            slowDownCallback : function() {
            }
        }
```

i change stopImageNumber with `stopImageNumber: 2,3` and `stopImageNumber 2 || 3`. but its not working..

is there anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's well work taking the [tour], even though you've been a member for more than two years. And you get a badge. :-)

Comment: im so sorry sir, i newbe in SO. I will try better in asking.. thank you for ur information :)

Comment: No worries! But please do use the "edit" link to fix the question. :-)

Comment: done sir :) can you halp me to solve my problem sir?

Comment: We still can't reasonably answer the question without reading the "Roulette Demo" page. The question must be *self-contained*. Quote and/or describe enough of what you're working with that someone can answer without following the link at all (pretend you don't even have the link to share).

Comment: thank you for ur attention sir.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the method directly, it looks like it only accepts a single integer value, null, or -1.

```
// x >= 0 or null or -1
```

https://github.com/akira-kuriyama/roulette.js/blob/master/roulette.js#L6

Here is how it is used:

```
p.stopImageNumber = $.isNumeric(defaultProperty.originalStopImageNumber) && Number(defaultProperty.originalStopImageNumber) >= 0 ? Number(defaultProperty.originalStopImageNumber) : Math.floor(Math.random() * p.imageCount);
```

https://github.com/akira-kuriyama/roulette.js/blob/master/roulette.js#L142

Comment: thank you for ur help sir.. but i mean, i just want to stop at 3 image.. can you halp me?

Comment: what code have you done? I recommend setting up a jsfiddle

Comment: no sir, i still try but its usless.. i newbe with code please halp me https://jsfiddle.net/drxwj30k/